# Bold text truncated with numberOfLines is too long

Tags: css, react-native, rendering, truncate

Working on a React Native project, I have run into an issue when using the numberOfLines prop on a Text component containing bold text. I have a component similar to this:

```
<Widecard {...props}>
  <Text numberOfLines={3} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    {props.title}
  </Text>
</WideCard>
```

It seems that numberOfLines can only calculate how many characters there are room for with a normal font weight and ignores whether the text has been styled as bold or italic, making the character width a little wider. Either that or the number of characters is calculated before fontWeight is applied.

As a result the truncated text will often be a little longer than what there is room for. The ellipses at the end of the string then overflow the container and are cut off.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know some kind of work-around?